# How can I tell PVS-Studio to ignore all of the files in a third party library when using CMake on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, pvs-studio

I am using PVS-Studio with CMake on Linux. I recently added a third party library to my project.

PVS-Studio is flagging possible issues in the header files for the third party library. How do I go about telling PVS-Studio to ignore the entire third party library when analyzing my code? When using PVS-Studio with Visual Studio on Windows I was able to do this with the PVS-Studio extension inside Visual Studio. On Linux I don't have that.

I've attached my CMakeLists.txt file to this project (it is pretty simple) plus the list of warnings emitted by PVS-Studio.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")
project(my_project)
include_directories($ENV{HOME}/code/repo/other/GSL/include)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(proj_srcs main.cpp notes.txt)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${proj_srcs})
include($ENV{HOME}/code/repo/other/pvs-studio-cmake-examples/PVS-Studio.cmake)
pvs_studio_add_target(TARGET ALL COMPILE_COMMANDS OUTPUT FORMAT errorfile)
```

Warnings

```
.../other/GSL/include/gsl/multi_span:663:1: warning: V547 Expression is always true.
.../other/GSL/include/gsl/multi_span:1163:1: warning: V560 A part of conditional expression is always true: totalSize <= (9223372036854775807L).
.../other/GSL/include/gsl/string_span:118:1: warning: V547 Expression 'cur != nullptr' is always true.
```

I am still having some trouble getting this to work.

In CMakeLists.txt I have:

```
# The header files for the C++ Standard Library are located in /usr/include.
# Unfortunately ARGS --exclude-path /usr/include does not suppress the warnings
# generated by Clang.
pvs_studio_add_target(TARGET ALL COMPILE_COMMANDS OUTPUT FORMAT errorfile ARGS --exclude-path /usr/include)
```

When building with Clang 12.0.0 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu PVS Studio generates hundreds of lines of warnings. For example,

```
--- snip ---
/include/c++/10/bits/stl_numeric.h:64:1: warning: V1061 Extending the 'std' namespace may result in undefined behavior.
/include/c++/10/numeric:80:1: warning: V1061 Extending the 'std' namespace may result in undefined behavior.
/include/c++/10/numeric:167:1: warning: V1061 Extending the 'std' namespace may result in undefined behavior.
/include/c++/10/numeric:226:1: warning: V1061 Extending the 'std' namespace may result in undefined behavior.
/include/c++/10/pstl/glue_numeric_defs.h:15:1: warning: V1061 Extending the 'std' namespace may result in undefined behavior.
--- snip ---
```

Does anybody know what might be wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this parameter:

```
-e [DIR], --exclude-path [DIR]
   Directory whose files are not necessary to check
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
pvs_studio_add_target(TARGET ALL
                      COMPILE_COMMANDS
                      OUTPUT FORMAT errorfile
                      ARGS -e /path/to/third/party -e /path/to/tests)
```